# devexpress chart not rendering the browser is zoomed out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress, devextreme

I have a problem with charts from @devexpress/dx-react-chart-material-ui.
I am using the pie chart in my application and noticed that when the user has browser zoom set to 67%, the series are not rendering at all (Chrome, tested on macOS and Windows).
Below is an example with following steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Open https://codesandbox.io/s/z6qd9?file=/index.js
2. Zoom out window view to 33%
3. **Refresh the page**
4. After refreshing the chart, it is gone. When you zoom in/out again (for example from 33% -> 25% -> 33% without refreshing the page), the chart is rendered correctly.

I know it's unlikely that anyone would browse the page with 33% zoom BUT in my application, the bug occurs even on 67% zoom which is used quite often.

Comment: I've found an issue logged that addresses this bug: https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-reactive/issues/3288 In the meantime, any workaround would be sublime

Answer (score 0):

New release of the library ultimately fixes the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).